# Negative upper bound value in genetic model estimate

Tags: confidence-interval, multivariate-analysis, genetics

I'm running twin models in which I estimate additive genetic and environmental influences in a bivariate model, mixing continuous and ordinal measures. 
In my model I estimated an overlap between E estimates (non shared environmental influences), which brings out the following output:

```
ACE.Re[2,1]   3.020748e-01         6.575223e-01        -7.953737e-01
```

What I don't understand is how the upper value can be negative? Has anybody else come across this problem?